# How to add values to zend registry in zend framework 2?

Tags: php, zend-framework

I need to pass id to another controller action in the controller. I try to the save id in ZendRegistry and get it into the target class.

```
$id=$_POST[eid];
Zend_Registry::set('id', $id);
```

I used above code but it isn't working. Please help me. Thanks.

Answer (score -3, accepted):

To SET the Value to Registry:

```
  require_once 'Zend/Registry.php';  
  $id=$_POST[eid];
  $registry = Zend_Registry::getInstance();  
  Zend_Registry::set('id',$id);
```

To GET the Value from Registry :

```
   $id = Zend_Registry::get('id');
```

[for further details click me](http://framework.zend.com/manual/en/zend.registry.using.html)

Comment: HTTP Error 500 (Internal Server Error):  An unexpected condition was encountered while the server was attempting to fulfill the request.

Comment: the above code has nothing to do with the error. i think u r initializing something wrong to your view

Comment: But ZF2 doesn't have Registry class